# Maximum Sample value for a given Sample Size and Distribution

Tags: distribution, sampling

Suppose a sample size of 100 samples are drawn randomly from an Exponential distribution. For a given mean of the exponential distribution (say μ), what could be the maximum possible sample value ? Is there any relationship to calculate the maximum sample value from the exponential distribution with given mean ?

Example :- Exponential Distribution, Sample Size N = 100 , μ=4 , Maximum Value in the sample = ?

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this over at http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0):

Infinity.  Mathematically, the range is zero to infinity for all exponentials, regardless of the mean or rate, so there's no finite upper bound on what the max could be.  The answer is different computationally, of course, but you could in principle use the memoryless conditional probability behavior of the exponential to write an infinite precision generator.

Bear in mind that infinity is not a number, so you will never generate a value of infinity.  That's why it has to be expressed as "any value you can conceive of it going to, it can go higher."

Bottom line is that there really is no finite max that can be specified unless you are willing to cap the upper tail probability you're willing to ignore.

Comment: If I fix the sample size as N, will it ever reach to infinity with given mean and distribution. I hope "No" . Can you clarify please?